# Need to click on a button which is drawn in a image view at any resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autolayout, imageview

Question is simple, answer I don't know...

I got imageView displaying an image with a lot of stuff and a drawn button in it. And of course I am using auto-layout and rotation.

The screen will be displayed at any iPhone resolution (Scale to Fill), on different device models, hence the button will render at different sizes and different positions.

What is the best way to assign an actual click to that area - which I repeat, will be displayed in different positions, calculated at runtime - without making complex calculations on the frame bounds relative to the original image size and button position?

Kinda lost here...thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: You can add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the imageView

Comment: button.target(forAction: #selector(yourMethod), withSender: button) Why do u even need to do any calculations to get click???

Comment: Guys, the image is large and the button is a rectangle in it. The image resizes with the device screen and so does the button. Gesture recogniser would have to be placed by calculation of button actual placement.

Answer (score 0):

if button is UIButton, than just add the target like button.target(...) & enable imageview.userInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: I guess u didn't get the question. There is a button as an rectangle drawn in an image. Need to map the area around that.